# Joining Arrow tables in R without overflowing memory or exceeding Acero's "bytes of key data" limit

Tags: r, bigdata, apache-arrow

I'm working with big data, using R and Apache Arrow. My data is split between two datasets, call them:

- `vals`: a hive-partitioned set of parquets, each row contains an ID (long string) and hundreds of columns of data (ints)
- `meta`: a parquet of meta-data, each row contains the same ID and some grouping variables.

To aggregate `vals` down to a manageable size I need to first join with `meta`. I believe that doing this in a memory-efficient, piecewise manner is exactly what Arrow excels at, but I can't make it happen.

Here's my attempt:

```
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)
vals = open_dataset(path_to_vals)
meta = open_dataset(path_to_meta)
temp = left_join(vals, meta, by='id') %>% 
  group_by(grouping_variables_from_meta) %>% 
  summarise(across(all_of(variables_from_vals), mean))
write_dataset(temp, 'some_path')
```

As soon as I invoke `write_dataset` my memory usage balloons. It seems to me that Arrow is trying to do the join by holding both tables in memory. Even if I temporarily sidestep this problem by requesting absurd amounts of memory from the cluster (not a long-term solution), the process eventually fails with:

`Error: Invalid: There are more than 2^32 bytes of key data.  Acero cannot process a join of this magnitude.`

I have used Arrow to summarise much larger datasets in the past with a) very little memory usage and b) no errors about too large key data. But, on those occasions I always had the grouping variables in a single dataset and didn't need to join them first. So, I'm a pretty sure the join step is where the problem lies.

Should I be doing this differently? Is there something I've misunderstood?

---

sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Rocky Linux 8.7 (Green Obsidian)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /n/sw/helmod-rocky8/apps/Core/R/4.3.1-fasrc01/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so 
LAPACK: /n/sw/helmod-rocky8/apps/Core/R/4.3.1-fasrc01/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.1.3     arrow_13.0.0.1  nvimcom_0.9-147

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.2.1 utf8_1.2.3       R6_2.5.1         bit_4.0.5       
 [5] tidyselect_1.2.0 magrittr_2.0.3   glue_1.6.2       tibble_3.2.1    
 [9] pkgconfig_2.0.3  bit64_4.0.5      generics_0.1.3   lifecycle_1.0.3 
[13] cli_3.6.1        fansi_1.0.4      vctrs_0.6.3      compiler_4.3.1  
[17] purrr_1.0.2      tools_4.3.1      pillar_1.9.0     rlang_1.1.1
```

Comment: It looks like some part of the query is not mapped to arrow cpp and forces the data to be loaded into R when the query is executed/used to write the data. Normally this should throw a not-implemented error when using datasets to avoid your exact situation. Scanning the docs/news.md I think the issue is all_of as everything else your are using is supported.

Could you try hardcoding/replacing all_of?

Comment: I tried `summarise(test=mean(just_one_variable))` but get the exact same result.
I can also pinpoint it to the join step by doing `left_join(vals, meta, by='id') %>% compute()` which gives the same result.

Comment: Which version of arrow are you using? Could you post a session info?

Comment: Too long for a comment so I added the sessionInfo() to the main post.
Looks like I'm a version behind the current release. Compiling Arrow on the cluster was a painful enough experience that I'd want to be confident that upgrading would solve my problem before sinking the time into it.

Comment: "Compiling Arrow on the cluster was a painful" a bit of a tangent to this post but I am the build system guy for the package so I have some tipps/would love feedback for what issues you are running into. We have pre-compiled libarrow binaries, on linux we don't default to using them but you can force it with LIBARROW_BINARY=TRUE, if there is no matching binary it will fallback to building from source. You could alternativly also install libarrow as a system library which pc will/should pick up or vcpkg,etc... and point the r package to it with ARROW_HOME

Comment: If I'm remembering right, the crux of the problem was that I was constrained to using [spack](https://spack.io/) to manage the libraries and there were constant conflicts between the broader system libraries and those in my spack environment. It was a while ago, but if I try installing Arrow version 14 (probably after my Christmas vacation, so late January) I will absolutely reach out to you with details.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way acero (the C++ execution engine that is used for the joins) stores the key data (uint32_t) joins with more than 4gb of key data are not supported at the moment.

The error message you are seeing is caused by a check to prevent data from being clobbered and silently returning broken results. But it seems there are some issues with that check that are being worked on in https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/37709 which could mean you are affected even with <4gb of key data.